# Using JavaScript to expand all replies in a Twitter thread

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to expand all replies in a Twitter thread. For example, https://twitter.com/Google/status/1542676601862729729

The following JavaScript will always find the next "Show replies":

```
document.querySelector("div.css-1dbjc4n.r-1iusvr4.r-16y2uox > div > span");
```

Therefore, I thought the solution would be:

```
var replies_found = document.querySelector("div.css-1dbjc4n.r-1iusvr4.r-16y2uox > div > span");

while (replies_found) {
  replies_found.click();
  replies_found = document.querySelector("div.css-1dbjc4n.r-1iusvr4.r-16y2uox > div > span");
}
```

However, this solution does not work, because apparently, querySelector cannot detect "Show replies" until I manually page down and put "Show replies" onto the screen.

Therefore, it seems like this problem (expanding all replies in Twitter thread) is not solvable programmatically (to me, at least). Can anyone think of a solution?

Comment: Maybe add a `window.scrollTo` and maybe a delay inside the loop?

Comment: The problem is not a delay, since I already have 5 seconds delay between clicks (not shown in my question, for brevity). However, I've never heard of window.scrollTo before. How would I use it to automatically scroll to the next "Show replies" location?

Comment: `The following JavaScript will always find the next "Show replies"` No, it will always find the first "Show Replies"

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo